# how does a {{content()}} function work in volt page phalcon framework

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I was following tutorial of the phalcon framework and came up with a volt engine and its view page. I was wondering how the content() function work in volt view pages?
and I'm also confused with the connection between the pages content?
The structure of the code is as follows:
 - views/index.volt
 - views/index/index.volt
 - views/layout/main.volt

The views/index.volt page inside the views is the first page to load at the beginning but how are they interconnected with the pages index/index.volt and layout/main.volt?
I've followed the tutorial from the official site of phalcon.
http://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/reference/tutorial-invo.html

Answer (score 3):

Phalcon has a hierarchical view structure with three levels: Layout, Controller and View.

When it is time to render a page Phalcon starts with the Layout. When Volt comes to a `{{content()}}` it renders the next view level down and adds that to the rendered view.

`{{content()}}` is an alias in Volt of `Phalcon\Mvc\View::getContent()`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the specific [View documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html).

The `{{ content() }}` is where the output of the next file down in the hierarchy will be placed. I.e. if you had a page file `myPage.volt` and a layout file `myLayout.volt` then the contents of `myPage.volt` would appear where the `{{ content() }}` line is inside `myLayout.volt`.